# Map induced by inclusion has image $0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring and $I\subseteq R$. Then the inclusion $\varphi:I^2\hookrightarrow I$ induces a map $$\varphi^*:Hom_R(I,R/I)\rightarrow Hom_R(I^2,R/I),\hspace{.5cm} \varphi^*(f)=f\circ\varphi$$ I want to show that $\text{im}(\varphi^*)=0$.

**My ideas:** Let $x\in I^2$ and let $f:I\rightarrow R/I$. Then it suffices to show that $f(\varphi(x))\in I$. I don't see the trick here, but I think that since the inclusion has a left inverse, $\varphi^*$ will be surjective (I've proved this).

Comment: The left inverse is not a homomorphism, in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the exact sequence
$0\to I^2\xrightarrow{\varphi} I\xrightarrow{\pi}I/I^2\to 0$; if you apply the functor $\operatorname{Hom}_R(-,R/I)$, you get the exact sequence
$$
0\to\operatorname{Hom}_R(I/I^2,R/I)
\xrightarrow{\pi^*}\operatorname{Hom}_R(I,R/I)
\xrightarrow{\varphi^*}\operatorname{Hom}_R(I^2,R/I)
$$
and you know from your question [Isomorphism of Hom sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176860/isomorphism-of-hom-sets) that $\pi^*$ is an isomorphism. By exactness, the kernel of $\varphi^*$ contains the image of $\pi^*$. Therefore $\varphi^*$ is the zero map.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

How do you describe an element of $I^2$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $i,j\in I$, $f(i.j)=i.f(j)$ since $f$ is an homomorphism of $R$-modules. If $y\in R/I, i\in I, i.y=0$, this implies that $i.f(j)=0$ . $I^2$ is generated by $\{i.j; i,j\in I\}$.

Comment: Where does $\varphi^*$ come into play? From what I can tell, we just showed that $Hom_R(I^2, R/I)=0$. Can you tell me how I'm mistaken?

Comment: $\phi^*=f\circ \phi$ is the restriction of $f$ to $I^2$ so you can also write $\phi^*(f)(i.j)=f(\phi(i.j))=f(i.j)$.

Comment: I follow now, thanks. See my edit, if you can.