# Combinatoric proof - Number of irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$

Tags: number-theory, zeta-functions

**Question** Is there a simple combinatoric proof that in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ :$\ \ \displaystyle \boxed{m \, N_m = \sum_{d | m} \mu(d) q^{m/d}}$  ?

The only proof I saw uses formal series :

---

> Let $M$ be the set of monic polynomials, $m_d = \#\{ f \in M, deg(f) = d\}$
>
> $P$ the set of prime/irreducible monic polynomials, $N_d= \#\{ f \in P, deg(f) = d\}$
>
> Then [by unique factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product)
>   $$\sum_{f \in M} t^{deg(f)} =\sum_{d=0}^\infty m_d t^d = \prod_{h \in P} (1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty t^{deg(h^k)}) = \prod_{d=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(1-t^d)^{N_d }}$$
>
> Taking the logarithm and using that $m_d=q^d$ we have
>   $$-\log(1-qt) = \log(\sum_{d=0}^\infty q^{d} t^d) = -\sum_{d=1}^\infty N_d\log(1-t^d)$$
>
> Using the series for $−\log(1−x)$ :
>   $$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{q^m}{m}t^m =\sum_{d=1}^\infty N_d\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{t^{dk}}{k}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty t^m \sum_{d | m} N_d\frac{d}{m}$$
>
> Hence $q^m=\sum_{d | m}d \, N_d$ and by Möbius inversion
>   $$m \, N_m = \sum_{d | m} \mu(d) q^{m/d}$$

Comment: Here's a proof via the inclusion-exclusion principle: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.0409.pdf

Comment: My combinatorial interpretation of this (admittedly somewhat unsatisfactorily) is that it's trivial to count the number of monic polynomials of a given degree, and you can work out how many of those are reducible if you already know how many irreducible polynomials there are of smaller degree. The difference of these two quantities is the number of monic irreducible polynomials. So the right-hand side is simply an inclusion-exclusion way of counting irreducibles in terms of monics.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Yes that's what says the formula $m \, N_m = \sum_{d | m} \mu(d) q^{m/d}$ but I now realize counting the numbers of roots (the number of elements in $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$ generating $\mathbb{F}_{q^d}$) makes it obvious

Comment: @PeterHumphries  And it becomes obvious once you think to $q^d$ as the number of elements in $\mathbb{F}_{q^d}$ instead of the number of monics in $ \mathbb{F}_q[x]$ of degree $d$

Comment: By the way, for this kind of thing, I greatly enjoyed Michael Rosen's book "Number Theory in Function Fields". It's very good at making the analogy clear between analytic number theory over $\mathbb{Z}$ compared to over $\mathbb{F}_q[t]$.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.0409.pdf) given by PeterHumphries :

in $m \, N_m = \sum_{d | m} \mu(d) q^{m/d}$

- $m N_m$ is the number of roots of irreducible polynomials of degree $m$
- while the RHS is the number of elements  $a \in \mathbb{F}_{q^m}$ such that $\mathbb{F}_{q^m} = \mathbb{F}_{q}(a)$, i.e. the number of elements in $\mathbb{F}_{q^m}$ once we removed the subfields : $\mathbb{F}_{q^d}, d |m$

The formula in the RHS (inclusion-exclusion principle) is based on $\# \mathbb{F}_{q^d} = q^d$ and $\mathbb{F}_{q^d} \subset \mathbb{F}_{q^e}$ iff $d | e$

Comment: Note $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_d) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_e)$ iff $d | e$ so I wonder if you can adapt this in some way to $\zeta_{ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)}(s)$.